# How is "ReactReduxContext.Consumer" working?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I wrote a demo to try to understand how "ReactReduxContext.Consumer" works, the main code like this:

**Hello.tsx**

```
export default function Hello() {
  return <ReactReduxContext.Consumer>
    {({store}) => {
      return <div>
        <ul>
          <input value={store.getState().name} onChange={(e) => store.dispatch(changeNameAction(e.target.value))}/>
          <div>{JSON.stringify(store.getState())}</div>
        </ul>
      </div>
    }}
  </ReactReduxContext.Consumer>
}
```

**Entry.tsx**

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Hello/>
  </Provider>,
  document.body
);
```

**State.ts**

```
export type State = {
  name: string
};
```

**reducer.ts**

```
const initStore: State = {
  name: 'aaa'
}

export default function reducers(state = initStore, action: ChangeNameAction): State {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'CHANGE_NAME':
      return {
        ...state,
        name: action.name
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**action.ts**

```
export type ChangeNameAction = {
  type: 'CHANGE_NAME',
  name: string,
}

export function changeNameAction(name: string): ChangeNameAction {
  return {
    type: 'CHANGE_NAME',
    name: name
  }
}
```

It renders correctly:

[image]

But if I type anything in the text field, the value doesn't change.

I'm not sure why it doesn't work.

Here is a tiny but complete demo of this question: https://github.com/freewind-demos/typescript-react-redux-context-consumer-demo

Comment: You are not supposed to import or consume `ReactReduxContext`. Use `useSelector` or `connect()` instead.

Comment: @DanPantry For this demo, my purpose is to understand how "ReactReduxContext.Consumer" works

Answer (score 3):

`ReactReduxContext` is a [React Context](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/components/Context.js) that contains the current Redux store.

The store reference *never changes* in normal operation, which means that anyone listening directly to the context in the manner you are doing will never see updates.

React Redux's `connect()` and `useSelector` both subscribe to the store and 'notify' React of the updates (usually by setting some state, which causes a re-render of the subscribed component).

You could implement your own primitive version of `useSelector` by doing this:

```
function useSelector(f) {
  const store = React.useContext(ReactReduxContent);
  const [state, setNextState] = React.useState(() => {
    return f(store.getState());
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    return store.listen(state => {
      setNextState(f(store.getState()));
    });
  }, [f, store]);

  return state;
}
```

React Context only propagates changes when the value passed to the provider changes, which is why you must subscribe to the store itself - as mentioned earlier, the store will never change in normal operation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and appreciate the custom selector solution. But I still have this question, why "ReactReduxContext.Consumer" exists? It doesn't quite useful since it just give us a static unchanged "store" reference

Comment: It is necessary for React Redux to function, but you as a user do not need to use it

Comment: Thanks, I think I need some more time to think about it

Comment: missing parenthesis on end of `setNextState(f(store.getState())`. Should be `setNextState(f(store.getState()))`.

Comment: Thanks! fixed it.